# PHP file creation does not work

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make it so that every time the person presses the submit button, a txt file will be created containing the information on the textboxes. After the form is submitted, it redirects to a different html file. But this does not work

THIS IS MY PHP CODE (File name:process.php)

```
<?php
                    $form = fopen("forms/openhouse_signup.txt", "w") or die("Error: Missing Forms on Server!");
                    if (!empty($_POST)){
                        $txt = "Parent's Name: ".$_POST['parentN']."\n";
                        fwrite($form, $txt);

                        $txt = "Email Address: ".$_POST['email']."\n";
                        fwrite($form, $txt);

                        $txt = "Postal Code: ".$_POST['postal']."\n";
                        fwrite($form, $txt);

                        $txt = "Phone Number: ".$_POST['phone']."\n";
                        fwrite($form, $txt);

                        $txt = "Child's Name: ".$_POST['childN']."\n";
                        fwrite($form, $txt);

                        $txt = "Child's Age: ".$_POST['childA']."\n";
                        fwrite($form, $txt);

                        $txt = "\n ----------------------------- \n";
                        fwrite($form, $txt);

                        fclose($form);
                        header('Location: done.html');
                    }
?>
```

MY HTML CODE (File Name:signup.html)

```
<h2 style="font-family:Arial, Sans-serif">Please Fill In The Following Boxes To Sign Up</h2>
                <form style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12pt" name="input" action="process.php" method="POST">
                    Full Name of Parent:<br> 
                    <input class="txtbox" type="text" name="parentN"><br><br>
                    Email Address:<br> 
                    <input class="txtbox" type="text" name="email"><br><br>
                    Postal Code:<br> 
                    <input class="txtbox" type="text" name="postal"><br><br>
                    Phone Number:<br> 
                    <input class="txtbox" type="text" name="phone"><br><br>
                    Full Name of Child:<br> 
                    <input class="txtbox" type="text" name="childN"><br><br>
                    Age of Child:<br> 
                    <input class="txtbox" type="text" name="childA"><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up!">
                </form>
```

Comment: That's a poor validity check, just testing for `if(!empty($_POST))`. What if the user creates Elements using firebug, or something? Just a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and it is working perfectly. So so far so good, then I have found this issue  that I think is yours. You may not have the rights to open and to write inside a file. To fix this you need to change its chmod to 777.
You can do it either by a command line:

```
chmod 777 filename.php
```

or a PHP instruction if you prefer:

```
chmod(filename.php, 777);
```

**Also chmod to 777 the form folder** to be able to create anything inside this folder.

Then I've ran again the code and it worked perfectly. Here is the output from the `.txt` file:

```
Parent's Name: a
Email Address: b
Postal Code: c
Phone Number: de
Child's Name: e
Child's Age: f

 -----------------------------
```

For more documentation on `chmod` see : http://php.net//manual/fr/function.chmod.php and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: Thank you, this is probably why. I will fix it right now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try after adding 'value' attribute in text-field as following :

```
   <form name="input" action="process.php" method="POST">
            Full Name of Parent:<br> 
            <input class="txtbox" type="text" value="" name="parentN"><br><br>
            Email Address:<br> 
            <input class="txtbox" type="text" value="" name="email"><br><br>
            Postal Code:<br> 
            <input class="txtbox" type="text" value="" name="postal"><br><br>
            Phone Number:<br> 
            <input class="txtbox" type="text" value="" name="phone"><br><br>
            Full Name of Child:<br> 
            <input class="txtbox" type="text" value="" name="childN"><br><br>
            Age of Child:<br> 
            <input class="txtbox" type="text" value="" name="childA"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up!">
        </form>
```